# Non-Periodic Boundary conditions for wave equation

Tags: symmetry, differential-equations, spherical-harmonics

I already know that when we have a problem with spherical symmetry and periodic boundary conditions in both angles the Helmholtz equation (like the equations that we find in physics when we have wave or diffusion equation)

$$ \left[ \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2 \sin(\theta)} \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} \left( \sin(\theta) \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} \right)+\frac{1}{r^2 \sin^2(\theta)} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \varphi^2}\right] \Psi (r,\theta,\varphi)=k^2 \Psi (r,\theta,\varphi)$$
with
$$ \varphi\in(0,2\pi) \quad \theta \in(0,\pi) \quad r\in(0,a) $$
have the solution in terms of Spherical harmonics

$$ \Psi (r,\theta,\varphi) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-l}^l R_{n,l}(r)\cdot Y_{l,m}(\theta,\varphi) $$

Where

$$ Y_{l,m}(\theta,\varphi)=(-1)^m \cdot \left[ \frac{2l+1}{4\pi} \frac{(l-m)!}{(l+m)!} \right]^{1/2}\cdot P^m_l[cos(\theta)] \cdot e^{im\varphi}  $$

and where $P^m_l[cos(\theta)]$ are the associated Legendre functions

I would like to know how can I  find with this result (using the symmetry of the problem and the Spherical harmonics/associated Legendre functions properties) the solution for a not full sphere surface. Specifically, I would like for spheres with $\varphi\in(0,\frac{2\pi}{p})$ and $\theta\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ with $p\in \mathbb{Z}$, for example:

1. The north pole of the sphere ($p=1$)
2. 3D first quadrant ($p=4$)
3. A maximum value of $\varphi$ in first quadrant (for example, $p=6$)

Comment: Where does $p$ all of a sudden pop up from?

Comment: Sorry it should be $p\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. It is just to don't have periodic conditions in $\varphi$

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks.